# Exclude config classes from spring context

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I have a class that configures Cassandra database:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { BASE_PACKAGE })
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String keyspaceName;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.datacenter-name}")
    private String datacenterName;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public CqlSessionFactoryBean session() {
        CqlSessionFactoryBean session = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        session.setKeyspaceName(keyspaceName);
        session.setLocalDatacenter(datacenterName);
        session.setPort(port);
        return session;
    }
...

}
```

And I have an empty test that just loads spring context

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

When I run it, I see this exception message:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

...

Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=29caef8c): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.copy(AllNodesFailedException.java:141)
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSystemSession(CqlSessionFactoryBean.java:498)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CqlSessionFactoryBean.java:451)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 166 more
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)
        at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.fail(ProtocolInitHandler.java:356)
        at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.writeListener(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:87)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:184)
        at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
        at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
        at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:76)
        at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.send(ProtocolInitHandler.java:193)
        at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler.onRealConnect(ProtocolInitHandler.java:124)
        at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.lambda$connect$0(ConnectInitHandler.java:57)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
        at app//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
        at app//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
        at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
        at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0()(Unknown Source)
```

As I understand, it tries to connect to the database but it cannot, thus, it fails.
I tried different ways to exclude this class from context loading like `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = CassandraConfig.class)` but then it fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes: com.myproject.test.config.CassandraConfig
```

Is there some advices or best practices how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting makes sense, `CassandraConfig` is not an autoconfiguration but a configuration class.

To exclude it you could use a Spring profile:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
public class CassandraConfig {
```

Then in your test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.profiles.active=test")
class ApplicationTest {
```

Comment: generally, it works but I also have controller, service and repository layers that depend on this config. so, they fails

Comment: Maybe you should provide a more detailed description. This answers what you asked...